# JWT private key and public key

Tags: spring, spring-boot, authentication, jwt

I have asked to create a JWT token for an API. For this I have use the jose4j dependency to generate and consume that token. I've given an example token that I've debbuged in jwt.io and it seems that I need a public and private key, as you can see in the signature below:

[image]

What I've done so far is this, following the documentation in jose4j bitbucket page:

```
public String createJWT() throws JoseException, MalformedClaimException {

        RsaJsonWebKey rsaJsonWebKey = RsaJwkGenerator.generateJwk(2048);;
        rsaJsonWebKey.setKeyId(keyId);

        JwtClaims claims = new JwtClaims();
        claims.setJwtId(keyId);
        claims.setIssuer(issuer);  // who creates the token and signs it
        claims.setAudience(audience); // to whom the token is intended to be sent
        claims.setSubject(subject); // the subject/principal is whom the token is about
        claims.setExpirationTimeMinutesInTheFuture(60); // time when the token will expire (10 minutes from now)
        claims.setGeneratedJwtId(); // a unique identifier for the token
        claims.setIssuedAtToNow();  // when the token was issued/created (now)
        claims.setNotBeforeMinutesInThePast(2); // time before which the token is not yet valid (2 minutes ago)



        // A JWT is a JWS and/or a JWE with JSON claims as the payload.
        // In this example it is a JWS so we create a JsonWebSignature object.
        JsonWebSignature jws = new JsonWebSignature();


        // The payload of the JWS is JSON content of the JWT Claims
        jws.setPayload(claims.toJson());

        // The JWT is signed using the private key
        jws.setKey(rsaJsonWebKey.getPrivateKey());
```

The thing is I don't know from where I'm suppose to get this private key, or what should it be.
I have also a keydata class with a username and a password, are those attributes my private key?

Then I have the consumer like this:

```
JwtConsumer jwtConsumer = new JwtConsumerBuilder()
                .setRequireExpirationTime() // the JWT must have an expiration time
                .setAllowedClockSkewInSeconds(30) // allow some leeway in validating time based claims to account for clock skew
                .setRequireSubject() // the JWT must have a subject claim
                .setExpectedIssuer("Issuer") // whom the JWT needs to have been issued by
                .setExpectedAudience("Audience") // to whom the JWT is intended for
                .setVerificationKey(rsaJsonWebKey.getKey())// verify the signature with the public key
                .setJwsAlgorithmConstraints( // only allow the expected signature algorithm(s) in the given context
                        AlgorithmConstraints.ConstraintType.PERMIT, AlgorithmIdentifiers.RSA_USING_SHA256) // which is only RS256 here
                .build(); // create the JwtConsumer instance
```

Where in this line: `.setVerificationKey(rsaJsonWebKey.getKey())// verify the signature with the public key` the code supponse to retrieve the public key.

So from where I'm suppose to get those key? Should I ask my collegues for them or what?

Comment: You have to known what alg is used to sign the JWT. It's given in the header of it. If it's an asymtric key, you need access to the public key corresponding to the private key whitch sign the JWK. If it's a symetric key, you have to known it. For exemple with openId Connect, when a JWT has an alg HSxxx, the key is symetric and it's the client_secret.

Comment: Hello! The alg is RS256

Comment: You have to access to the RSA public key to verify the signature of the JWT. This key is used of the private key whitch made the signature.